# .NET 3rd Party Dependency Decoupling and versioning

Tags: c#, .net, api, service, versioning

We have a .Net Service that reaches out to a 3rd party API DLL that we must reference. This 3rd party API has several different versions. i.e. 5.9, 5.10, 5.11. Even though the calls are the same, the 3rd party's API is locked to the same version of the main System. If we referenced 5.11 we could not talk to a clients system that was running 5.9 or 5.10.

Is there a way to decouple this 3rd party software and make our service version agnostic to minimize recompiling and code changes?

We're currently running on .net 4.8 because their API does not support anything in the .net core/ .net 5+ frameworks.